# Accessing Moodle web service via django

Tags: python, django, web-services, moodle

[Im trying to access moodle via moodle-ws-client package but im getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qby5l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `moodle-ws-client`, which has last been updated in 2013. I recommend, try to find another library that's up to date. If you can't find one, you can use their regular REST APIs to make calls with python `urllib`.

You can also try this lib: https://github.com/mrcinv/moodle_api.py

Comment: The REST API seems interesting. But how to approach this? I only know the basics of REST API. Any kind of advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Checkout https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ lib. Then you need to learn, how to make REST calls with that lib, it supports it out of the box. Finally, you need to check the documentation on moodle to figure out, which endpoints they have and how to call them. Checkout https://github.com/mrcinv/moodle_api.py on how they do it.

Comment: Thankyou so much.

Comment: If that solves your problem, can you please accept my answer?

Comment: The rest api supports upto 3.5 but im currently using 3.8.2 will that affect anything?

Comment: The Moodle API? Becase REST APIs are not concerned with Python, you don't need python to make API calls.

Comment: The plugin. I'm learning django so i thought it would be a nice place to start since im using moodle as a student.

Comment: So in general, yes, it will matter a lot if you are using python 3.8, but a library you use only supports up to 3.5. Between 3.5 and 3.8 a lot has changed.

Comment: hey i just got the time to work on this but i keep getting ssl validation erros. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: What error exactly? Maybe your ssl lib is outdated?

Comment: just used verify = False and it worked!
I am using a self generated ssl on my moodle

Comment: Hey! so i wanted to make multiple users in one go using this code but when i use a loop it says invalid parameter exception. Is there a fix?

x=0
while x<=5:
    User(username = str(Username[x]), firstname = str(Firstname[x]), lastname = str(Lastname[x]) , email = str(Email[x]), password = str(Password[x])).create()
    x=x+1

Comment: If you want to create a user, check out the Django docs on how to do it, your way is wrong as far as I can see. I think from now on, your issues are within Django so not sure how much I can help you. The docs are very good though, just take a look at them and you will find your solutions I am sure.